# Textview does not change textcolor

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have an problem setting textcolor on some part of a Textview.
The text is defined to have the color white in the layout-xml.
When the user chooses the write answer in the game this method call is triggered:

```
this.Question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout1Question);    
this.Question.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color = 'green'>CORRECT: </font>") + this.CurrentQuestion.getFillin());
```

Here I want the CORRECT -part to show green text while the rest should be white as default.
But the whole text is shown in white. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: It works if I remove the second part, hence:

`this.Question.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color = 'green'>CORRECT: </font>"));`

works okay.

Comment: try "<font color = \"green\">CORRECT: </font>"

Comment: @PadmaKumar : Still the same (text is shown in white)...

Comment: try giving explicit color value like #0F0..

Comment: I ran your code removing some part runs fine  
this.Question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout1Question);    
this.Question.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color = 'green'>CORRECT: </font>")

Comment: It works if I remove the second part, hence:
this.Question.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color = 'green'>CORRECT: </font>"));
@SunnyKumarAditya Yeah, used tried that

Then it writes CORRECT: in green. So it seems that the problems occours when I add the other text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `geFillin()` call to `fromHtml` parameter. May be the string concatenation is casting the `Spanned` string back to simple string.

```
this.Question.setText(
       Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'>CORRECT: </font>" + this.CurrentQuestion.getFillin()));
```